# Парсинг типа данных PointF

Tags: c#

```
PointF location = PointF.Parse(node["Location"].InnerText);
```

Добрый день!Мне необходимо пропарсить PointF.Метод Parse не подходит.Не могу найти аналог этого метода для PointF.Или то что я делаю в корне не верно?

```
Написал свой метод.

public void ParsePoint(string str)
    {
        string[] tokens = str.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string valueX = tokens[0];
        string valueY = tokens[1];
        float x; float y;
        if (float.TryParse(valueX, out x) && float.TryParse(valueY, out y))
        {
            Location = new PointF(x, y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Видимо, его надо самому написать. Что представляет из себя `node["Location"].InnerText`?

Comment: Вот это Location="400;-150".

Comment: Ну, напишите свой парсер, в чем проблема?

Comment: @Kama, откуда вы их парсите?

Comment: @Yaroslav,С xml файла.Там есть элемент location в котором указаны координаты точки.Вместо массива double[] для обработки координат, я решил взять PointF.

Comment: а что такое PointF?
PointF location = PointF.Parse(node["Location"].InnerText);
приведите его реализацию

Comment: если я Вас равносильно понял, то в PointF нет метода Parse!
[PointF Struct](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pointf?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Все верно.Придется видимо писать парсинг.

Comment: Покажите весь xml целиком. Возможно, десериализация будет проще всего.

Answer (score 0):

для примера:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class Location
{
    public Int32 X;
    public Int32 Y;

    [XmlElement("Location")]
    public List<Location> nodes;
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
            <Location>
                <X>50</X>
                <Y>20</Y>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <X>60</X>
                <Y>30</Y>
            </Location>";

        var reader = new StringReader(xml);
        var result = (Location)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Location)).Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```